# Create a "bank transaction" and to apply specific rules

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, sequelize.js

I need to create a simulation of a bank transaction with a few specific rules. For example, if the type of the payment is done with a debit card, it must be charged a fee of 3.2%.

For now I could not set up the rules in the controller yet. Could someone help me out?
Here is how my current controller looks like:

```
class TransactionController {
  async store(req, res) {
    const { type_transaction } = req.body;

    if (type_transaction === 'debit') {
      const value = value - 32 / 10;
    }
    const transaction = await Transaction.create(req.body);
    return res.json(transaction);
  }
}
```

Here is the **Transaction** model:

```
class Transaction extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        value: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        description: Sequelize.STRING,
        type_transaction: Sequelize.STRING,
        installments: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      {
        sequelize,
      },
    );

    return this;
  }

// ... CONTINUES
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case we need to get the value from the `req.body`like the code below:

```
async store(req, res) {
    const { type_transaction, value, installments } = req.body;
    if (type_transaction === 'debit') {
      req.body.value = Number(value) + 28 / 10;
     // ... CONTINUES
    }
```